# Как передать и удалить текст чекбокса?

Tags: android, checkbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс строка добавлялась и наооборот удалялась. И при нажатии на кнопку Show Toast появлялся Toast с выделенными чекбоксами ?

Я знаю как получить строку и как добавить, но вот как удалить строку если чекбокс false ?

Comment: либо сделайте связку чекбокс+текствью и прячьте (`setVisibility(GONE/INVISIBLE`) последний, либо присваивайте `checkBox.setText("")`.

Comment: Не вы не поняли, текст не к чекбоксу, а к строке котороя выводится при нажатии на копку. Вот я добвляю к строке текст из чекбокса с помощью String s = checkbox.getText.toString(); а как мне теперь удалить эту строку если я убрал галочку с чекбокаса?? Т.е мне нужно же передать в Toast строчку с выделенными чекбоксами !

Comment: Проверяйте все чекбоксы в момент нажатия кнопки, зачем городить их заранее

Answer (score 0):

```
private String strChekbox1 = "";
private String strChekbox2 = "";
private String strChekbox3 = "";

@Override
public void onCreate()... {

chekbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
chekbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
chekbox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkbox1.isChecked) {
                strCheckbox1 = checkbox1.getText().toString()
            }

            if (checkbox2.isChecked) {
                strCheckbox2 = checkbox2.getText().toString()
            }

            if (checkbox3.isChecked) {
                strCheckbox3 = checkbox3.getText().toString()
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, strChekbox1 + strChekbox2 + strChekbox1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId) {
        case R.id.checkbox1:
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox1.setText("Check box 1 on");
            } else {
                checkbox1.setText("Check box 1 off");
            }
        break;
        case R.id.checkbox2:
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox2.setText("Check box 2 on");
            } else {
                checkbox2.setText("Check box 2 off");
            }
        break;
        case R.id.checkbox3:
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox3.setText("Check box 3 on");
            } else {
                checkbox3.setText("Check box 3 off");
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Объявлете переменные текста, вешаете на чек боксы чекед листенер, и в каждом клике проверяете состояние, если true чекбок задает один текст если false другой и переменная strCheckbox принимает этот текст, затем в клике кнопки делаете условие, если бок в состоянии true получить его текст и отобразить в тост сообщении.

p.s. код писал от руки, возможны мелкие упущения)